# Stub an internal functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, stubbing

I want to stub a internal function in my code when unit testing it, example:

```
//foobar.js
const uuid = require('uuid');

function foo() {
    console.log('uuid: ' + uuid.v4());
    // Lots of timers
}
exports._foo = foo;

function bar() {
    //Logic...
    foo();
    //Logic...
}
exports.bar = bar;
```

And the unit test:

```
// test/foobar.js
const chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    proxyquire = require('proxyquire'),
    sinon = require('sinon');

describe('bar', () => {
    it('call foo', () => {
        let foo = proxyquire('./foo.js', {
                uuid: {
                    v4: () => {
                        return '123456789';
                    }
                }
            }),
            fooSpy = sinon.spy(foo._foo);

        foo.bar();
        expect(fooSpy.calledOnce);
    });
});
```

Now, when unit testing `bar`, I can spy on `foo` just fine, and it is quite fine.
However, the real `foo` make a lot of time consuming calls (DB calls, file IO...), and while I could use proxyquire to stub all `fs` and db calls to terminate immediately, that would duplicate code from the test of `foo`, be unreadable, and being bad altogether.

The simple solution would be to stub `foo`, but proxyquire doesn't seems to like that. A naive `foo._foo = stubFoo` didn't worked either. Rewire doesn't seems to handle this either.

What I could do would be to make a file that import and export foobar.js, and use proxyquire on it, but the idea itself is already bad.

How can I stub the `foo` function when testing `bar`?

Answer (score 0):

Sinon is perfectly capable to handle this if done correctly, you just need to remember sinon replace references in the object, and `export` is not where the function is declared. But with the same code and tests, a simple modification to bar make it works:

```js
function bar() {
    //Logic...
    exports._foo();
    //Logic...
}
```